# Finding the limit of a sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis

I have a sequence of functions $\{\frac{x}{{(1+x)}^n}\}$ and I am trying to find $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{x}{(1+x)^n} = f$.

I know the definition of point-wise convergence, $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{x}{(1+x)^n} = f$ if for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $N = N(x, \epsilon) \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \geq N$, $|f - f_n| < \epsilon$.

However, I am not quite sure how to proceed though I suspect that $0$ is the limit since $f_n(0) = 0$ and $f_n(1) = \frac{1}{2^n}$ and so $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2^n} = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

You simply have to compute the limit
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x}{(1+x)^n}
$$
for each $x \in \mathbb R$ and see what you get. For $|1+x| > 1$, it's actually quite simple : we have 
$$
\left| \frac{x}{(1+x)^n} \right| = |x| \frac 1{|1+x|^n} \underset{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0. 
$$
Using this argument, you can also check that for $1+x = 1$ (i.e. $x=0$) the sequence $f_n(x)$ is constant equal to $0$, and for $1+x = -1$, the sequence $f_n(x)$ alternates between $2$ and $-2$. and thus does not converge. I leave up to you to figure out what happens when $|1+x| < 1$.

Remark : since you suspected that the limit was $0$ after computing two values of $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$, I wanted to add that the limit is not a real number, but a real function. So you might want to expect different values at different points, i.e. $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$ might depend on $x$.

Hope that helps,

Comment: For $|1 + x| < 1$, the sequence $f_n(x)$ would not converge.